# What's the relation between PES and LSA?

Tags: neuroscience, theoretical-neuroscience, nef

In "[Learning by stimulation avoidance: A principle to control spiking neural networks dynamics](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0170388)" by Sinpayen et al. a learning rule called Learning by Stimulation Avoidance (LSA) is presented. According to the abstract, this learning rule:

- Scale to at least a hundred neurons
- Explains synaptic pruning
- Replicates results from "[Development, learning and memory in large random networks of cortical neurons: lessons beyond anatomy](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/quarterly-reviews-of-biophysics/article/development-learning-and-memory-in-large-random-networks-of-cortical-neurons-lessons-beyond-anatomy/910AE0F1F27FD2695764AD93D55E752B)" by Marom and Shadoff

How does the mechanism compare to the [Prescribed Sensitivity Error (PES)](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/17386/4397) learning rule used by the NEF? Is LSA compatible with the NEF?